# Help me parse this sentence, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis

> Observable as a tendency of our culture is a withdrawal of belief in psychoanalysis: we no longer feel that it can solve our emotional problems.

This is from GRE verbal tests.

From what I guess the author want to say, I parse it like this:

> Observable as a tendency (of our culture is a withdrawal (of belief in psychoanalysis)): we no longer feel that it can solve our emotional problems.

But in that way, the part before the colon ("Observable as a tendency") lacks a verb. How do you guys think?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sentence is structured like this:

> Subject clause: **a withdrawal of belief in psychoanalysis**
>
> Verb: **is**
>
> Predicate phrase: **observable as a tendency of our culture**
>   ("observable" is an adjective modifying the subject, and the rest of
>   the phrase modifies "observable")

"We no longer feel that it can solve our emotional problems" is a second, complete clause that can stand alone as a separate sentence.  The whole sentence could be written as such:

> **A withdrawal of belief in psychoanalysis is observable as a tendency
>   of our culture. We no longer feel that it can solve our emotional
>   problems.**

Comment: The whole sentence *should* have been written that way. The topic isn't what is 'observable', or 'tendency', or 'our culture', it is 'withdrawal of belief in psychoanalysis', which is buried deep at the end of the first clause, way after everything that is being said about it. In fact, 'as a tendency of our culture' could be blue-pencilled entirely, just say 'is observable' or more concretely 'can be observed' or 'exists' or 'belief in psychoanalysis is being withdrawn'. I would also have used a colon rather than a semicolon. Was this written by a psychoanalyst? ;-)

Comment: You can't truly tell whether this sentence *should* have been written this way without seeing the context. It is good writing practice to reorder sentence structure to better connect with the previous sentence. On the other hand, this ordering of the clauses makes the sentence so impenetrable that I'm not sure that any improvement in connectivity justifies it.

Comment: @Peter: I didn't originally register the significance of *GRE verbal tests* cited as the source. Didn't know what GRE was, to be honest. But having noted that your own MIT says GRE is one of only three acceptable language qualifications for non-native speakers, they're obviously credible. OP's text probably isn't hard to actually understand for most competent native speakers, just a bit convoluted. Which I guess is quite reasonable, given GRE's context and purpose here.

Comment: @Peter Shor I can take a good guess at the context, and indeed I did so. The original sentence is certainly completely impenetrable. Which 'this' in 'this ordering of the clauses' are you referring to?

Comment: @EJP: by "this", I meant the original one.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence uses "non-standard" word order, IMHO in a misplaced attempt to seem more academic and authoritative. The natural order would be...

*A withdrawal of belief in psychoanalysis is observable as a tendency of our culture.*

...wherein **is** is the *Verb*, preceded by *Subject*, followed by *Predicate*. The part after the semicolon can effectively be treated as another sentence, as @spotlightdev notes.

Comment: This kind of inversion is quite common in academic writing, and serves a pragmatic function (though it can make the writing harder to understand, as here). It is a stylistic variant of the cleft sentence "What is observable as a tendency in our culture is ...". Cleft sentences are often used in everyday speech as well, and serve to make prominent the **focus** (here, "observable ... ") as opposed to the **topic** ("Withdrawal ... ")

Comment: @Colin: In retrospect my first sentence is a bit snarky. I don't object to the inversion (or the "passive voice") as such. But given the superfluous *"observable as"* to boot, I do think the whole sentence is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: @Colin: one pragmatic function of odd order in sentence structure is to better connect with the previous sentence. Reordering sentence structure can make a dramatic improvement in the readability of paragraphs. On the other hand, I'm not sure it could justify this particular convoluted sentence.